# how to read from text file in assets in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

how to add text file in asset folder in flutter and read all data from it. I already have an external text file with data in it. I just need to add it in assets folder and start reading from it. but how?

Comment: Read the ["Loading text assets"](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images) section from this documentation article.

Comment: Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/config.json');
}

Comment: but its .json. my file is .txt

Comment: do i need to convert it to .json first???

Comment: Nah should be fine as a .txt. Try it!

Comment: ok thanks. i am giving it a try

Comment: thanks. it is working perfectly fine.